# Server settings with 36GB handling app+data

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.7, performance-tuning

I'm setting up a server to handle a multi-site configuration on a beta application for a partner in a new business venture.

Trying to assess sane values for MySQL.

Currently I have set:

```
key_buffer_size         = 128M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
max_heap_table_size = 256M
query_cache_limit = 4M
query_cache_size = 512M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=5G
```

Does this seem reasonable?

36GB is total RAM on the system. It needs to run 50-100 instances of the same web application. I'm guessing allocating 1/4 of the total ram to MySQL is about right? Perhaps I should up the innodb_buffer_pool closer to 7G.

MySQL Version:

```
 innodb_version          | 5.7.12
```

Obviously am not a DBA and may be missing providing relevant information to give a proper answer. Please excuse my ignorance. I'm willing to learn. If more information is needed please let me know and I'll modify this question to include it.

Comment: The 36GB is available RAM? If you will have any nontrivial MyISAM tables then 128MB might not be enough for key buffer, but that depends.. 5GB for buffer pool is quite small if you have 36 available, give it 16-20GB. QC of 512MB is too big, it will take lot of time to invalidate entries on updates. Set it to ~32MB or [disable it entirely](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/136814/64556).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. 36GB is total ram on the system. It needs to run 50-100 instances of the same web application. I'm guessing allocating 1/4 of the total ram to MySQL is about right? Perhaps I should up the innodb_buffer_pool closer to 7G. I will check that link and take your thoughts into consideration.

Comment: If the same machine has to run such application then yes, there is less memory remaining for mysql. Check the available unused memory well before making the buffer pool bigger. When there is not enough memory, mysql is often the victim to be killed by the system because its buffers are usually the biggest offender. And you don't want a server to swap either. If the multiple instances of that app need a lot of memory, maybe check if you could put 64GB in there (if your data are bigger than the 5GB currently available).

Answer (score 1):

```
query_cache_size = 512M
```

is really bad.  Don't use more than 50M.  Otherwise, *whenever* a write occurs, *all* entries in the QC for that table need to be purged; this will take too long.

Other tips: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory

When you get further along, the most likely performance issue will be the lack of optimal indexes on tables.  After that will come queries that are not written as well as they should be.

Only after you have been running for some time, with real queries, can we address all the settings (`SHOW VARIABLES`) by looking simultaneously at `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`.

Comment: I set it to 24m